Having trouble deploying the ERC-2470 singleton factory to a new chain
I'm trying to deploy a new singleton factory to my own chain, but I'm not able to get the instructions listed on the page to work. Specifically I'm not able to deploy it from the one-time deployer address, and am hence unable to get the expected contract address. I tried the methods described here: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2470, calling provider.broadcastTransaction on the raw transaction threw an error about how only txes that had replay protection were allowed (explicitly prohibited by the EIP), and generating the transactions from its properties resulted in either a deployment by my signer or, when i set the 'from' field to the one-time deployer address, a from address mismatch. Here is my current code:
async function deploySingletonFactory() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners()
  await deployer.sendTransaction({
    to: '0xBb6e024b9cFFACB947A71991E386681B1Cd1477D',
    value: ethers.parseEther('0.0247'),
    chainId: (await deployer.provider.getNetwork()).chainId,
  })
  await deployer.sendTransaction({
    nonce: 0,
    gasPrice: 100000000000,
    value: 0,
    data: '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',
    gasLimit: 247000,
    chainId: (await deployer.provider.getNetwork()).chainId,
    v: 27,
    r: '0x247000',
    s: '0x2470',
  })
}

any advice would be much appreciated

Can you add the actual error message and stacktrace to the question?

I'm not familiar with this ERC. In any case it looks like an ethers' problem, so you can try sending the transaction with something else. Since it looks like you have already signed it, you can use forge cast publish. You can also look if your blockchain has a block explorer that supports publishing txs, like https://lineascan.build/pushTx
